# Condition variable WinAPI does't work. Why?

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi, visual-c++

I want to synchronize threads, that generates automatically. I write such code. This code periodically write names of every thread in such sequence they are generated.

But when I run my code, sometimes I have a nice result and sometimes I have something such a bug: all are hang (sleep with clearly black screen). It happens accidentally.

With debugging I understand that sometimes child thread doesn't want to wake up. Who can tell: why? And how can I fix that?

I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Professional on Windows 10 x64.
And my code:

main.cpp

```
#include "ThreadManager.h"
#include "ThreadFuncs.h"

int main() {
    ThreadManager mng(2.0, 1.3);
    mng.runAll();

    Sleep(100000);

    return 0;
}
```

ThreadFuncs.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "Sync.h"
#include "ThreadManager.h"

#include "ThreadFuncs.h"

DWORD WINAPI threadPrinter(LPVOID ptr)
{
    ThreadManager* manager = reinterpret_cast<ThreadManager*>(ptr);
    if (!manager)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    CRITICAL_SECTION cs;
    InitializeCriticalSection(&cs);
    EnterCriticalSection(&cs);

    while (!manager->isStopPrinting)
    {
        EnterCriticalSection(&manager->workWithFlags);

        for (auto it = manager->flags.begin(); it != manager->flags.end(); ++it)
        {
            (*it)->operation = OPERATION_START_WRITING_NAME;
            WakeConditionVariable(&(*it)->canWork);

            SleepConditionVariableCS(&(*it)->isEndWork, &cs, INFINITE);
        }

        LeaveCriticalSection(&manager->workWithFlags);

        Sleep(manager->showInterval * 1000);
    }

    LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);
    DeleteCriticalSection(&cs);

    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI threadGenerator(LPVOID ptr)
{
    ThreadManager* manager = reinterpret_cast<ThreadManager*>(ptr);
    if (!manager)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    while (!manager->isStopGeneration)
    {
        manager->generateNewThread();

        Sleep(manager->createNewThreadInterval * 1000);
    }

    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI threadChild(LPVOID ptr)
{
    Sync* s = reinterpret_cast<Sync*> (ptr);
    if (s == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    std::string name = "Th_" + std::to_string(static_cast<long long>(s->index));

    CRITICAL_SECTION cs;
    InitializeCriticalSection(&cs);
    EnterCriticalSection(&cs);

    while (true)
    {       
        SleepConditionVariableCS(&s->canWork, &cs, INFINITE);

        if (s->operation == OPERATION_EXIT_THREAD)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (s->operation == OPERATION_START_WRITING_NAME)
        {
            std::cout << name << " ";
            WakeConditionVariable(&s->isEndWork);
            continue;
        }

        WakeConditionVariable(&s->isEndWork);
    }

    LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);
    DeleteCriticalSection(&cs);

    return 0;
}
```

ThreadManager.h

```
#pragma once

#include <windows.h>
#include <deque>
#include "Sync.h"
#include "ThreadFuncs.h"

class ThreadManager
{
    std::deque <Sync *> flags;
    CRITICAL_SECTION workWithFlags;

    friend DWORD WINAPI threadGenerator(LPVOID);
    friend DWORD WINAPI threadPrinter(LPVOID);

    HANDLE printerThread;
    HANDLE generatorThread;

    const double showInterval;
    const double createNewThreadInterval;
    bool isStopGeneration;
    bool isStopPrinting;    

public:
    ThreadManager(const double& showInterval, const double& createNewThreadInterval);
    ~ThreadManager();

    void generateNewThread();
    bool removeThread();            //kill random thread
    bool removeThread(int index);

    void runAll();
    void stopAll();

    int getNumOfThreads() const;
};
```

ThreadManager.cpp

```
#include "ThreadManager.h"


ThreadManager::ThreadManager(const double& showInterval, const double& createNewThreadInterval) :
    showInterval(showInterval), createNewThreadInterval(createNewThreadInterval), isStopGeneration(true), isStopPrinting(true)
{

    InitializeCriticalSection(&workWithFlags);

    printerThread = NULL;
    generatorThread = NULL;

}

int ThreadManager::getNumOfThreads() const
{
    return flags.size();
}

void ThreadManager::runAll()
{
    //run generation
    isStopGeneration = false;

    if (generatorThread != NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    generatorThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, threadGenerator, this, /*run immediately*/ 0, NULL);
    if (generatorThread == NULL)
    {
        //Stream::log("Error creating generation thread");
        isStopGeneration = true;
    }

    //run printing
    isStopPrinting = false;

    if (printerThread != NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    printerThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, threadPrinter, this, /*run immediately*/ 0, NULL);
    if (printerThread == NULL)
    {
        //Stream::log("Error creating printer thread");
        isStopPrinting = true;
    }
}

void ThreadManager::stopAll()
{
    //stop generation
    if (!generatorThread)
    {
        return;
    }

    isStopGeneration = true;

    WaitForSingleObject(generatorThread, INFINITE);

    CloseHandle(generatorThread);

    generatorThread = NULL;

    //stop printing
    if (!printerThread)
    {
        return;
    }

    isStopPrinting = true;

    WaitForSingleObject(printerThread, INFINITE);

    CloseHandle(printerThread);

    printerThread = NULL;
}

ThreadManager::~ThreadManager()
{
    stopAll();

    while (!flags.empty())
    {
        removeThread(flags.size() - 1);
    }

    DeleteCriticalSection(&workWithFlags);
}

void ThreadManager::generateNewThread()
{
    static int newIndex = 0;
    Sync* s = new Sync();

    s->index = newIndex;
    newIndex++;

    s->threadHandle = CreateThread(NULL, 0, threadChild, s, /*run immediately*/ 0, NULL);
    if (s->threadHandle == NULL)
    {
        //Stream::log("Error creating new thread");
        delete s;
        return;
    }

    EnterCriticalSection(&workWithFlags);
    flags.push_back(s);
    LeaveCriticalSection(&workWithFlags);
}

bool ThreadManager::removeThread(int index)
{
    EnterCriticalSection(&workWithFlags);

    if (flags.size() <= index || index < 0)
    {
        LeaveCriticalSection(&workWithFlags);
        return false;
    }

    Sync* s = flags[index];
    flags.erase(flags.begin() + index);

    s->operation = OPERATION_EXIT_THREAD;
    WakeConditionVariable(&s->canWork);

    WaitForSingleObject(s->threadHandle, INFINITE);

    delete s;

    LeaveCriticalSection(&workWithFlags);

    return true;
}

bool ThreadManager::removeThread()
{
    EnterCriticalSection(&workWithFlags);
    int size = flags.size();
    LeaveCriticalSection(&workWithFlags);

    if (!size)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return removeThread(rand() % size);
}
```

Sync.h

```
#pragma once

#include <windows.h>

#define OPERATION_EXIT_THREAD 1
#define OPERATION_START_WRITING_NAME 2

struct Sync
{
    CONDITION_VARIABLE canWork;
    CONDITION_VARIABLE isEndWork;
    HANDLE threadHandle;        //handle to thread
    int operation;              //operation type: 1 - exit, 2 - start writing name
    int index;                  //thread index

    Sync()
    {
        InitializeConditionVariable(&canWork);
        InitializeConditionVariable(&isEndWork);
        threadHandle = NULL;
        operation = 0;
        index = -1;
    }

    ~Sync()
    {
        if (threadHandle)
        {
            CloseHandle(threadHandle);
        }
    }
};
```

---

Updated:

Stack trace (that I understand that):
[image: Stack trace]

Comment: Please provide [mcve] - key word being **minimal**. But typically, the problem for such behavior is a race condition, somewhere in your code.

Comment: Can you use the Visual Studio debugger to look at all your threads and see what they are doing?  You should be able to get a stack trace for each  of them.  I was able to do something like that with an open-source toolchain (MinGW and GDB).

Comment: I try to do that. But it's really minimal that can I do, because in other times it may not be verifiable

Comment: @DavidGrayson You want this like stack trace?
[pic](https://image.ibb.co/fP3gBF/image.png)

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but have you considered just using Win32's thread pools? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686766.aspx

Comment: Why are your worker threads creating local `CRITICAL_SECTION` instances? That is not necessary, especially since they are not being used for anything useful anyway.  Just get rid of them.

Comment: `EnterCriticalSection(&manager->workWithFlags);` vs `SleepConditionVariableCS(&(*it)->isEndWork, &cs, INFINITE);` !! need be `SleepConditionVariableCS(&(*it)->isEndWork, &manager->workWithFlags, INFINITE);` and Remy Lebeau absolute right - local critical section absolute senseless - because only gingle thread can assign it

Comment: `SleepConditionVariableCS(&s->canWork, &cs, INFINITE);` in `threadChild` - also wrong. you use wrong critical_sections

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry, but if I remove this blocks and write the second parameter of SleepConditionVariableCS to NULL, I have an error on it:  
> Access violation writing location 0x000..008 on this function

Comment: @AJIOB - are you not understand that use local(in stack) critical section absolute senseless ?

Comment: @RbMm I don't want to make free `&manager->workWithFlags` critical section when I run Sleep... function. I only want to wait some signal

Comment: @AJIOB - again are you understand that use local(in stack) critical section absolute senseless ? because only single thread have pointer-use this critical section

Comment: you need work only with `&manager->workWithFlags` CS

Comment: @RbMm I understand, that I don't make free global `&manager->workWithFlags`, but I want to wait my condition variable. In use to lock my global critical section (cs) when I call printings, but I don't free it to another threads. I free to another threads my local cs. Or I don't understand something?

Comment: yes, you not understand. `CRITICAL_SECTION cs;` absolute senseless - because no other thread have pointer to this `cs` and not will be use it. until you clear not understand it - you not make progress.

Comment: @RbMm , ok, I understand this. How can I wait my signal without it in child?

Comment: remove all `CRITICAL_SECTION cs;` replace `&cs` to `&manager->workWithFlags` - `without it` - without what ?? try reply this for self

Comment: @RbMm , "it" is equivalent to `CRITICAL_SECTION cs`. "in child" is equivalent "child thread"

Comment: again and last - use *CS* exist sense only when several threads (can be > 1) use this *CS*. in your case - in stack declared *cs* - is used always only by single thread. all threads have own (different) *cs* objects. use this absolute senseless and rough error

Comment: @AJIOB: RbMm is correct. Declaring a local `CRITICAL_SECTION` variable that does not get shared with other threads is completely useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `threadPrinter()` and `threadChild()` functions are not syncing threads correctly.  You are creating a new local `CRITICAL_SECTION` that is useless because other threads have no access to it, so it is not actually locking access to anything.  You are passing that local `CRITICAL_SECTION` to `SleepConditionVariableCS()` when you should be passing `manager->workWithFlags` instead.  But doing so introduces a new logic hole, because once a thread unlocks `workWithFlags` to wait on a condition variable, other threads are free to modify the contents of `flags`, which you are not checking for when the waiting thread re-acquires the `workWithFlags` lock when the condition variable is signaled.

Based on what you are attempting to do, you probably shouldn't be using condition variables at all.  A condition variable is meant to be used to unlock an acquired lock (either a Critical Section or a Slim Reader/Writer lock) while waiting for the variable to be signaled, and then re-acquire that same lock again once signaled.  That is not what you need in your code.  Using signalable events would make more sense.  Look at `CreateEvent()`, `SetEvent()`/`ResetEvent()`, and `WaitForSingleObject()`.  Signal an event to start some work, and signal another event when that work is finished.  You don't need to use condition variables for that.